# Requisição GET OkHttp Java

Tags: java, okhttp

Estou utilizando `Postman`, e ao fazer uma requisição `GET`, ocorre tudo numa boa e retorna o `JSON` com os dados.Porém ao pegar o código em java(abaixo), dessa requisição e executa-lo, me é entregue a seguinte mensagem `code=406, message=Not Acceptable`, o que é estranho  ja que funciona  de boas no Postman.Alguem sabe oq é?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://api.sualoja.com.br/clientes")
  .get()
  .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer d0f36dfb6ba2d153a29f4410411f737e3a6e205c")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "0465578e-2915-c482-d425-8c00ee97ec6d")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Tentei utilizar outra forma de fazer requisição utilizando `Unirest` mas  código abaixo porém me retornou o msm erro, mas com essa mensagem a mais:`Unable to resolve Accept header to a representation`, lembrando que peguei esse código do Postman também, e que lá ele funciona tranquilo.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("http://api.sualoja.com.br/clientes")
            .header("authorization", "Bearer 256ce87661709544aa32e6e97f779e0e5d9aa842")
            .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .header("postman-token", "23b4718d-3831-cf52-dc0a-b07a3f8caa1e")
            .asString();
```

Usei o método para mostrar os headers, e são retornados esses headers `Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Server=[nginx/1.10.2], Connection=[keep-alive], Date=[Tue, 03 Oct 2017 20:05:16 GMT], Content-Type=[application/problem+json], X-Powered-By=[PHP/7.1.10]`

Testei com o código representado em shell que o Postman me possibilita pegar, e funcionou de boa, trouxe todos os dados no terminal, porém preciso fazer isso em java.

GENTE Finalmente consegui resolver.Eu simplesmente acrescentei esta linha a minha requisição GET `.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; q=0.5")`, e pelo que eu entendi, voce vai ter q acressentar uma nova linha  dessas para cada tipo de arquivo que o seu servidor retorna, por exemplo:

```
`.addHeader("Accept", "application/hal+json; q=0.5")
 .addHeader("Accept", "application/json; q=0.5")
 .addHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`
```

aah e o meu código ficou assim. (Usando OkHttp):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://api.sualoja.com.br/clientes")
            .get()
            .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer 1c2b5f30582b4cf2831812487a34d48646580829")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json; q=0.5")
            .addHeader("postman-token", "57989a0f-8dec-d104-c6e7-b6e2cb64be97")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Comment: acho que está faltando o content type no seu header

Comment: botei assim `.addHeader("content-type", "json")` e continuou o msm erro,porém no postman continuou dando certo

Comment: tenta `.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")`

Comment: ainda persiste no erro

Comment: no postman, dá pra ver quais headers ele está enviando, está igual ?

Comment: Sim, o postman só esta enviando este `Authorization:Bearer 922da365f641a4bb2ba9d06d9d5ca88233d26260`. Retirei os outros e só deixei o `authorization`e também não funcionou